# Linux pipe : Capturing realtime output of ping via popen

Tags: c++, c, linux

Linux/C/pipes:

How can I capture the output of ping command using popen(Or similar system calls).
Currently popen will wait until ping is finished. Then output will be dumped together.

Pseudo code:

```
fp= popen("ping x.x.x.x", "r");
while(!feof(pFp))
{
   if(fgets(fp ...) // <==currently the code blocks here until ping finishes in popen
   { 
       printf(...real time ping output here);
   }
}
```

Comment: C or C++? Your code looks like C.

Comment: You are probably suffering from buffering.  Use pipe(2) for more control.

Comment: @cdarke: won't help. The problem is that ping is buffering its output. I would definitely consider this a bug in ping. If it knows it won't have any more output for up to a second (when it sleeps) then it should flush its output before sleeping...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not waiting until ping is finished. Rather, ping is waiting until the `stdout` buffer fills up before writing anything. The only ways to avoid this involve pseudo-ttys. Either you should abandon `popen` and write the code to run the ping child process yourself and use a pseudo-tty to communicate (this is easy with the nonstandard but widely available `forkpty` function) or you could write a wrapper program that runs ping through a pseudo-pty and grabs the output, and writes it *without buffering* to `stdout`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried setvbuf(fp, NULL, _IONBF, 0)) too. I expected since buffering is disabled, output shall be immediately available. I dont understand why this didnt work. It looks like I have to do what you suggested.

Comment: That won't help. All that does is disable buffering on your *input buffer*. But the problematic buffering is inside the ping program in its *output buffer*. You have absolutely no control over that.